# Actual size of an HTML element n Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to make 10000% sure that an HTML element is not invisible?
At the moment I am doing:

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

if (element.style.visibility !== 'hidden') && atLeastTen(element.clientWidth,
        element.clientHeight, element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight,
        element.scrollWidth, element.scrollHeight, rect.height, rect.width) {
    console.log("Element is visibile!");
    return true;
} else {
    console.log("Element is invisible!");
    return false;
}

function atLeastTen() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var v = arguments[i];
        console.log("CHECKING V:", v);
        if (v < 10) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this feels a little lame...
Ideas?

Comment: Isn't `100%` enough? ;-)

Comment: Depends on what your definition of "visible" is. Apparently you count a 9 pixels x 9 pixels sized element invisible? What about elements with zero opacity? Fully transparent images? `display:none`? Empty elements with transparent background? Elements outside the viewport?

Comment: Two downvotes... what the hell?

Comment: @Merc Did you even see my answer? `:O`

Comment: Saw it and loved it! And accepted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to check two things:

1. Visibility to eyes and DOM:

   1. Check `display`.
   2. Check `visibility`.
   3. Check `opacity`.
2. Whether it is inside the viewport.

   1. Get the co-ordinates and dimensions of the element.
   2. Get the dimensions of the viewport.
   3. Create a range of both.
   4. Check for intersection.

You may need to do everything for its parents too!!!

You can easily translate this into JavaScript using jQuery or none. And just checked with `:visible` from jQuery, the docs say:

> We’ve changed the logic behind the :visible and :hidden selectors
>   (which were used throughout jQuery to determine the visibility of an
>   element).
>
> This is how the logic has changed:
>
> - In jQuery 1.3.1 (and older) an element was visible if its CSS “display” was not “none”, its CSS “visibility” was not “hidden”, and
>     its type (if it was an input) was not “hidden”.
> - In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0.
>
> What does this change mean? It means that if your element’s CSS
>   display is “none”, or any of its parent/ancestor element’s display is
>   “none”, or if the element’s width is 0 and the element’s height is 0
>   then an element will be reported as hidden.
>
> What is the benefit of making this switch? The result is two-fold:
>
> - The performance is much, much, better. (See below.)
> - An element is reported as “hidden” if it’s inside a “hidden” element (something that wasn’t possible before, without the use of a plugin.

In simple terms, you can check for the visibility by this small code:

```
$(element).is(":visible");
```